# Getting error 1264 in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error (1264 Out of range value for column 'estimate' at row 1) Does anyone know what this means as I am not to sure.

```
CREATE TABLE reading(
    meter_code CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    `when` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    display DECIMAL(9,3) NOT NULL,
    estimate BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT pri_reading 
PRIMARY KEY (`when`, meter_code),
    CONSTRAINT reading_FK
FOREIGN KEY (meter_code)
    REFERENCES meter (`code`) 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE 
    ON DELETE CASCADE );
```

This is what i am trying to insert.

```
INSERT INTO reading VALUES ('G1','2016.11.01','200','1');
```

Comment: Remove the `' '` from the `'1'` and retry

Comment: Yep that worked thank you :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BIT` data type accepts only `0` and `1`, `b'0'` and `b'1'` or `0b0` and `0b1`. The string `'1'` is not a valid BIT value.

Also note that `'2016.11.01'` is not a valid DATETIME value. You should use either `'2016-11-01'` or `'2016-11-01 00:00:00'`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Please increase the type length of your column "estimate" or change to string type

Comment: type lens == type length?